# How to add font-face into a bootstrap theme

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-face

I have downloaded [Bootstrap magic theme](https://github.com/pikock/bootstrap-magic)

The basic structure of project is as:

[image: project]

Where fixed.html is main html file, scss-variables.json is json file where we define scss variables in json format and angular code convert it into sass.

Now I want to add gibson font into this theme, I tried adding it by adding fonts files under app\lib\angular\docs\components and then using it in 
app\lib\angular\docs\css\docs.css as below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gibson';
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_0_0.eot');
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_0_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gibson';
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_1_0.eot');
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_1_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gibson';
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_2_0.eot');
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_2_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_2_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_2_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gibson';
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_3_0.eot');
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_3_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_3_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_3_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gibson';
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_4_0.eot');
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_4_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_4_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_4_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gibson';
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_5_0.eot');
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_5_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_5_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_5_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gibson';
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_6_0.eot');
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_6_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_6_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_6_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gibson';
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_7_0.eot');
  src: url('../components/gibson/313E30_7_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_7_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../components/gibson/313E30_7_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Then further defining a class where using font-family:'Gibson' and then assigning that class in fixed.html
But this solution is not working.

What is wrong in my implementation? And how I can use font-face property within scss-variables.json file?

Comment: Are you sure that the ../components/gibson is correct? Do you want Gibson to be the font for the entire theme? Did you place `font-family: 'Gibson'` in the CSS body {...}?

Comment: ZimSystem Now I have used S3 live location for font face and kept them in bootstrap-editor\app\scss\reboot.scss. Now I am able to use the font by adding it into $font-family-sans-serif within \bootstrap-editor\scss\styles\lib\bootstrap\_variables.scss. But I am not sure if this is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have firstly added fonts into S3 and then added @font-face url in bootstrap-editor\app\scss\reboot.scss. Where it I checked that now I can use my newly created font-family by adding it:

```
html
{
 font-family: Gibson
}
```

Now when I removed all the styling from any of my class it uses this font-family.

So finally I added font-face in above file.
And as mahan in his answer stated I I used $font-family-sans-serif to implement Gibson through out the theme.

Answer (score 2):

```
$font-family-sans-serif:      -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol" !default;
$font-family-base:            $font-family-sans-serif !default;
```

---

You need to override **`$font-family-sans-serif`** or  **`$font-family-base`** variables. They are defined in `_variables.scss`. I have overridden  **`$font-family-sans-serif`** because all of my fonts are `sans-serif`.

```
$font-family-sans-serif: 'Gibson', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol" !default;
```

Comment: mahan how I can add new @font-face into such theme. In which file I should add my @font-face?

Comment: When I define @font-face in type.scss file and use it as font family then it does not work. Thanks for answering.